# Do I need to create a dummy variable?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

Im running a multiple regression model and therefore need to create dummy variables for a categorical predictor variable. This variable is 'YSK87' and its values in the dataset correspond to the following:

VALUE       LABEL
1     =   1 Person
2     =   2 Persons
3     =   3 Persons
4     =   4 or more Persons

Since almost all the values - apart from '4' - represent that same number of persons, would I have to create a dummy variable for YSK87? I understand that R would have noticed if it needed a dummy variable and would have created them if not. However, once I ran the regression model, looking at the output, I couldnt see any new variables that were supposed to be dummies.

Comment: Did you make the variable a "factor" in R?  If not, R would have assumed it was numeric, not something it needed to create dummy variables for.

Comment: I didnt not. That seems to be the best thing to do at the moment. Would that be an acceptable option though? (changing it to a factor and then carrying out the regression?)

Comment: Seems reasonable. Just be aware R will select a referent group automatically for dummy coding, when you code the variable as a factor. You might be happy with its default selection of referent group, or you might not (in which case you will need to manually [re]code it).

Comment: variable <- factor(YSK87,labels=c("label1","label2","labeln"))

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the R function `ifelse(test_expression,x,y)`.
(reference: https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/ifelse-function)

In your case, refer to the following code (person is a variable name):

`ifelse(person==1,1,0)->new1
ifelse(person==2,1,0)->new2
ifelse(person==3,1,0)->new3
ifelse(person=>4,1,0)->new4`

Or if you want to carry out the regression, try to use this code according to the above comment,
`lm(Y~factor(person), data=XXX)`.